# CSS: Place a Button/Text at the Bootom Right of a Div with content

Tags: html, css

I want to place some content at the bottom right content of a div and I came up with this:

```css
#superDiv,
#childDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#childDiv {
  z-index: 30;
  float: right;
  position: bottom;
}
```

This is a Plunk I have made
http://plnkr.co/edit/WaP5Pde7CXnAfnW3QybF?p=preview

What am missing?

Comment: There is no `position:bottom`...that's the place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code into this:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#superDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index:10;
  position: relative;
}

#childDiv{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 30;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`position: bottom` doesn't exist. And you don't need `float:right` because you are using absolute positions.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
#superDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#childDiv {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px; /* 5px margin-top + 5px margin-bottom */
  right: 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#childDiv {
    z-index: 30;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WaP5Pde7CXnAfnW3QybF?p=preview) to do as you want it. I've removed the `#childDiv` from the

```css
#superDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:relative; /* Note the change in position absolute -> relative */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

after this I've put your `#childDiv` to:

```css
#childDiv{
  z-index: 30;
  float:right;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

which positions it at the bottom right of your `#superDiv`.